# Oracle get the IDs of the inserted record

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have the below query

```
insert into amalgam_care (id, name, activestatus, incorpcountry, sourcetable, sourcesystem)
select fund_id, fund_name, active, domicile, 'EMIS_FUNDS', 'EMIS' from EMIS_FUNDS  
where status in (2, 3, 4) and active = 1 order by fund_id
```

I want to get the IDs of inserted records returned to me

I have tried below methods without success

```
insert into amalgam_care (id, name, activestatus, incorpcountry, sourcetable, sourcesystem)
select fund_id, fund_name, active, domicile, 'EMIS_FUNDS', 'EMIS' from EMIS_FUNDS  
where status in (2, 3, 4) and active = 1 order by fund_id RETURNING ID INTO :1
```

tried with the returning key word it did not work (table has an ID column which is not an auto generated or auto incremented column , neither it is the primary key)

Secondly in my java program I use prepared statements

```
String sql = "insert into amalgam_care (id, name, activestatus, incorpcountry, sourcetable, sourcesystem) select fund_id, fund_name, active, domicile, 'EMIS_FUNDS', 'EMIS' from EMIS_FUNDS  where status in (2, 3, 4) and active = 1 order by fund_id";
try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql,new String[] {"ID"})) {
                preparedStatement.setFetchSize(fetchSize);
                ResultSet rs1 =preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                if (rs1.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs1.getString("ID"));
                }
}
```

Above also fails with the below error

```
Caused by: Error : 933, Position : 233, Sql = insert into amalgam_care (id, name, activestatus, incorpcountry, sourcetable, sourcesystem) select fund_id, fund_name, active, domicile, 'EMIS_FUNDS', 'EMIS' from EMIS_FUNDS  where status in (2, 3, 4) and active = 1 order by fund_id RETURNING ID INTO :1 , OriginalSql = insert into amalgam_care (id, name, activestatus, incorpcountry, sourcetable, sourcesystem) select fund_id, fund_name, active, domicile, 'EMIS_FUNDS', 'EMIS' from EMIS_FUNDS  where status in (2, 3, 4) and active = 1 order by fund_id RETURNING ID INTO ?, Error Msg = ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Any input on this will be highly appreciated

I just want to get the IDs of the inserted records via prepared statements immediately back. my table column is named ID (ID is neither auto generated, nor the primary key)

Comment: According to [syntax diagram](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/img_text/single_table_insert.html) `returning` is only possible for `values` clause, not for subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, you must use "executeUpdate" not "executeQuery". To get back the inserted PK you can use "INSERT ... RETURNING column_name INTO ?" in an anonymous block or in a procedure "INTO an_OUT_param". In both cases, you must register an OUT parameter in the Java code.

Comment: execute update do not return the result set but only an int value which tells me no of rows inserted right ? thats why i have used exeucteQuery since it returns me the result set . Is my raw query wrong ? i have added an out param to it with returning

Comment: The ID of the inserted row will be in the OUT parameter that you will have to "stmt.getXXX(N)", not the result of the executeUpdate function.

Answer (score 1):

there is no such method, you can return the value to a variable : `INSERT INTO <table> VALUES (<values>) RETURNING ID into <variable>`

Comment: i do not use the values keyword , but directly use the SELECT key word to fetch from another table. I have tried inserts with values keyword and returning it works, but it doesnt work for the above query i have mentioned. i am wondering whether the returning part is read as a part of the second query which causes the error .. do u know a way around?

Comment: Use type for construction: insert RETURNING  bulk collect INTO type

Comment: Give parametr type in java code

Comment: You better not use this construct. you make life difficult for yourself.

Comment: give one request to java, and you're done

Answer (score 1):

That returning clause makes sense only inside a pl/sql block, and not in some SQL statement sent from Java or some other client. That is why it doesn't work.
A pl/sql block means basically somethign like below:

```
Declare 
  /* variable declarations as needed*/
  v_ret number;
begin
  /* several SQL statements as needed*/
  insert into x_table (... /* list of columns*/
  ) values (
  /* values to insert*/'
  x_id
  ...
  ) returning x_id into v_ret;     
end;
```

I never recall having used returning with an insert select. Why? Because that select may possibly return no rows whatsoever or may return several rows. How could that work then with a simple variable?
In case a DML (could be insert select or could be even an update or delete) may affect several rows you should use returning bulk collect, like in the example at https://doyensys.com/blogs/returning-clause-with-bulk-collect/